# kernel is not retaining writes to global cl_mem object

Tags: opencl

I have a setup where I'm sharing a memory object between multiple devices. Im trying to call a kernel multiple times to accumulate some values. On the CPU this is working fine. On the GPU, the subsequent calls are not seeing the results from the previous call. Here is the kernel with debugging statements.

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
__kernel void mgrid_sum(__global double *ar,            
                        __global double *ap,           
                        __global double *az,            
                        __global const double *temp_ar,
                        __global const double *temp_ap,
                        __global const double *temp_az,
                        double current) {
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    if (i == 0) {
        printf("1 %6i %12.5e %12.5e %12.5e %12.5e %12.5e %12.5e %12.5e\n", i, ar[i], ap[i], az[i], temp_ar[i], temp_ap[i], temp_az[i], current);
    }
    ar[i] += temp_ar[i]*current;
    ap[i] += temp_ap[i]*current;
    az[i] += temp_az[i]*current;
    if (i == 0) {
        printf("2 %6i %12.5e %12.5e %12.5e %12.5e %12.5e %12.5e %12.5e\n", i, ar[i], ap[i], az[i], temp_ar[i], temp_ap[i], temp_az[i], current);
    }
}
```

I have two sets of memory objects. My `temp_` memory buffer is loads up new values for before each kernel call. Since each device works on a independent chunk of memory, I was hoping that I didn't need to sync the memory buffers until after I have finished all my kernel calls. The host code is

```
// Define memory objects. The host only needs these values at the very end.
a_r = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY, buffer_size, NULL, NULL);
a_p = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY, buffer_size, NULL, NULL);
a_z = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY, buffer_size, NULL, NULL);

// Define temp memory objects. This will only be written to by the host and read by the kernel.
cl_mem temp_ar = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_WRITE_ONLY, buffer_size, NULL, NULL);
cl_mem temp_ap = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_WRITE_ONLY, buffer_size, NULL, NULL);
cl_mem temp_az = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_HOST_WRITE_ONLY, buffer_size, NULL, NULL);

// The first six kernel arguments don't change.
clSetKernelArg(sum, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &a_r);
clSetKernelArg(sum, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &a_p);
clSetKernelArg(sum, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &a_z);
clSetKernelArg(sum, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), &temp_ar);
clSetKernelArg(sum, 4, sizeof(cl_mem), &temp_ap);
clSetKernelArg(sum, 5, sizeof(cl_mem), &temp_az);

size_t totalsize = 0;
for (device_info *device : cpu_devices) {
    size_t worksize;
    clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(sum, device->id, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(size_t), &worksize, NULL);
    device->max_work_group_size = worksize;
    totalsize += worksize;
}
for (device_info *device : gpu_devices) {
    size_t worksize;
    clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(sum, device->id, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(size_t), &worksize, NULL);
    device->max_work_group_size = worksize;
    totalsize += worksize;
}

size_t n_chunks = array_size/totalsize;
size_t remainder = array_size%totalsize;

size_t offset = 0;
for (device_info *device : gpu_devices) {
    device->m_offset = offset;
    device->m_chunk = n_chunks*device->max_work_group_size;
    offset += device->m_chunk;
}
for (device_info *device : cpu_devices) {
    device->m_offset = offset;
    device->m_chunk = n_chunks*device->max_work_group_size;
    offset += device->m_chunk;
}
cpu_devices.back()->m_chunk += remainder;

cl_event event;
std::vector<cl_event> buffer_events;
std::vector<cl_event> unmap_events;

// Make sure the a_ memory starts with zero.
const cl_char pattern = 0;
for (device_info *device : gpu_devices) {
    offset = device->m_offset*sizeof(cl_double);
    size_t fill_size = device->m_chunk*sizeof(cl_double);
    clEnqueueFillBuffer(device->queue, a_r, &pattern, sizeof(cl_char), offset*sizeof(cl_char), fill_size*sizeof(cl_char), 0, NULL, &event);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);
    clEnqueueFillBuffer(device->queue, a_p, &pattern, sizeof(cl_char), offset*sizeof(cl_char), fill_size*sizeof(cl_char), 0, NULL, &event);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);
    clEnqueueFillBuffer(device->queue, a_z, &pattern, sizeof(cl_char), offset*sizeof(cl_char), fill_size*sizeof(cl_char), 0, NULL, &event);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);
}
for (device_info *device : cpu_devices) {
    offset = device->m_offset*sizeof(cl_double);
    size_t fill_size = device->m_chunk*sizeof(cl_double);
    clEnqueueFillBuffer(device->queue, a_r, &pattern, sizeof(cl_char), offset*sizeof(cl_char), fill_size*sizeof(cl_char), 0, NULL, &event);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);
    clEnqueueFillBuffer(device->queue, a_p, &pattern, sizeof(cl_char), offset*sizeof(cl_char), fill_size*sizeof(cl_char), 0, NULL, &event);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);
    clEnqueueFillBuffer(device->queue, a_z, &pattern, sizeof(cl_char), offset*sizeof(cl_char), fill_size*sizeof(cl_char), 0, NULL, &event);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);
}

// For each iteration load the value of current set the temp_ buffer value.
// Temp buffer values are obtained by mapping the memory object to the host 
// and writing to the memory object directly.
for (size_t i = 0, e = extcur.size(); i < e; i++) {
    clSetKernelArg(sum, 6, sizeof(cl_double), extcur.data() + i);

    cl_command_queue cpu_queue = cpu_devices.back()->queue;

    std::stringstream ss_ar;
    ss_ar << "ar_" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << i + 1;
    std::stringstream ss_ap;
    ss_ap << "ap_" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << i + 1;
    std::stringstream ss_az;
    ss_az << "az_" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << i + 1;

    cl_double *temp_buffer;
    nc_inq_varid(ncid, ss_ar.str().c_str(), &temp_varid);
    temp_buffer = static_cast<cl_double *>(clEnqueueMapBuffer(cpu_queue, temp_ar, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE_REGION, 0, buffer_size, static_cast<cl_uint>(last_events.size()), last_events.data(), NULL, NULL));
    nc_get_var(ncid, temp_varid, temp_buffer);
    clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(cpu_queue, temp_ar, temp_buffer, 0, NULL, &event);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);

    nc_inq_varid(ncid, ss_ap.str().c_str(), &temp_varid);
    temp_buffer = static_cast<cl_double *>(clEnqueueMapBuffer(cpu_queue, temp_ap, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE_REGION, 0, buffer_size, static_cast<cl_uint>(last_events.size()), last_events.data(), NULL, NULL));
    nc_get_var(ncid, temp_varid, temp_buffer);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);
    clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(cpu_queue, temp_ar, temp_buffer, 0, NULL, &event);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);

    nc_inq_varid(ncid, ss_az.str().c_str(), &temp_varid);
    temp_buffer = static_cast<cl_double *>(clEnqueueMapBuffer(cpu_queue, temp_az, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE_REGION, 0, buffer_size, static_cast<cl_uint>(last_events.size()), last_events.data(), NULL, NULL));
    nc_get_var(ncid, temp_varid, temp_buffer);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);
    clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(cpu_queue, temp_ar, temp_buffer, 0, NULL, &event);
    buffer_events.push_back(event);

    for (cl_event event : last_events) {
        clReleaseEvent(event);
    }
    last_events.clear();

    // Call kernels. These should wait until the memory objects are fully written.
    for (device_info *device : gpu_devices) {
        offset = device->m_offset;
        size_t fill_size = device->m_chunk;
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(device->queue, sum, 1, &offset, &fill_size, NULL, static_cast<cl_uint>(buffer_events.size()), buffer_events.data(), &event);
        last_events.push_back(event);
        offset += fill_size;
    }
    for (device_info *device : cpu_devices) {
        offset = device->m_offset;
        size_t fill_size = device->m_chunk;
        clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(device->queue, sum, 1, &offset, &fill_size, NULL, static_cast<cl_uint>(buffer_events.size()), buffer_events.data(), &event);
        last_events.push_back(event);
    }

    for (cl_event event : buffer_events) {
        clReleaseEvent(event);
    }
    buffer_events.clear();
}
```

I was expecting that after the first kernel call, the would just stay on the device until. However the output for the first GPU device shows the values written by the previous kernel call are not being retained. The output from my debug statements shows this

```
1      0  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  1.17641e-05  2.32558e-05 -3.04041e-05  4.20712e+03
2      0  4.94930e-02  9.78400e-02 -1.27913e-01  1.17641e-05  2.32558e-05 -3.04041e-05  4.20712e+03

# The first three values should be 4.94930e-02  9.78400e-02 -1.27913e-01 not zero.
1      0  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00 -1.33115e-21  1.44679e-07  0.00000e+00  1.11479e+03
2      0 -1.48396e-18  1.61287e-04  0.00000e+00 -1.33115e-21  1.44679e-07  0.00000e+00  1.11479e+03

1      0  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00  2.94903e-24 -3.56183e-06  0.00000e+00  1.46293e+04
2      0  4.31422e-20 -5.21071e-02  0.00000e+00  2.94903e-24 -3.56183e-06  0.00000e+00  1.46293e+04

# This call correctly retained the values of the previous call.
1      0  4.31422e-20 -5.21071e-02  0.00000e+00  6.39571e-22  1.25141e-05  0.00000e+00 -9.38901e-02
2      0  4.30821e-20 -5.21083e-02  0.00000e+00  6.39571e-22  1.25141e-05  0.00000e+00 -9.38901e-02

1      0  4.31422e-20 -5.21071e-02  0.00000e+00  8.62591e-22 -1.69898e-06  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
2      0  4.31422e-20 -5.21071e-02  0.00000e+00  8.62591e-22 -1.69898e-06  0.00000e+00  0.00000e+00

1      0  4.31422e-20 -5.21071e-02  0.00000e+00 -1.79097e-05 -3.44107e-22  4.79035e-05 -4.39945e+02
2      0  7.87928e-03 -5.21071e-02 -2.10749e-02 -1.79097e-05 -3.44107e-22  4.79035e-05 -4.39945e+02

1      0  4.31422e-20 -5.21071e-02  0.00000e+00 -3.54518e-24  1.54271e-07  0.00000e+00  7.54929e+03
2      0  1.63786e-20 -5.09424e-02  0.00000e+00 -3.54518e-24  1.54271e-07  0.00000e+00  7.54929e+03

1      0  1.63786e-20 -5.09424e-02  0.00000e+00  1.77797e-08 -3.33409e-08 -6.29109e-09  1.03658e+03
2      0  1.84302e-05 -5.09770e-02 -6.52124e-06  1.77797e-08 -3.33409e-08 -6.29109e-09  1.03658e+03

1      0  1.63786e-20 -5.09424e-02  0.00000e+00 -1.47516e-05  8.13733e-06  2.78991e-06  0.00000e+00
2      0  1.63786e-20 -5.09424e-02  0.00000e+00 -1.47516e-05  8.13733e-06  2.78991e-06  0.00000e+00

1      0  1.63786e-20 -5.09424e-02  0.00000e+00  5.12265e-12  1.55708e-07 -1.05426e-11  0.00000e+00
2      0  1.63786e-20 -5.09424e-02  0.00000e+00  5.12265e-12  1.55708e-07 -1.05426e-11  0.00000e+00
```

Is it doing an implicit synchronization between calls?

**Update**

Here is the information about the devices.

```
Platform Name   : Apple
Device Name     : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
Device Type     : CPU
Supports Double : True
Address Bits    : 64
Max Work Size   : 1
Extensions      : cl_APPLE_SetMemObjectDestructor  
                  cl_APPLE_ContextLoggingFunctions 
                  cl_APPLE_clut 
                  cl_APPLE_query_kernel_names 
                  cl_APPLE_gl_sharing 
                  cl_khr_gl_event 
                  cl_khr_fp64             
                  cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics 
                  cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics 
                  cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics  
                  cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics 
                  cl_khr_byte_addressable_store 
                  cl_khr_int64_base_atomics 
                  cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics 
                  cl_khr_3d_image_writes 
                  cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer 
                  cl_APPLE_fp64_basic_ops 
                  cl_APPLE_fixed_alpha_channel_orders 
                  cl_APPLE_biased_fixed_point_image_formats 
                  cl_APPLE_command_queue_priority
m_offset        : 731392
m_chunk         : 3080

Platform Name   : Apple
Device Name     : AMD Radeon R9 M370X Compute Engine
Device Type     : GPU
Supports Double : True
Address Bits    : 32
Max Work Size   : 256
Extensions      : cl_APPLE_SetMemObjectDestructor 
                  cl_APPLE_ContextLoggingFunctions 
                  cl_APPLE_clut 
                  cl_APPLE_query_kernel_names 
                  cl_APPLE_gl_sharing 
                  cl_khr_gl_event 
                  cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics 
                  cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics 
                  cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics            
                  cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics 
                  cl_khr_byte_addressable_store 
                  cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer 
                  cl_khr_depth_images 
                  cl_APPLE_command_queue_priority 
                  cl_APPLE_command_queue_select_compute_units 
                  cl_khr_fp64
m_offset        : 0
m_chunk         : 731392
```

Comment: Does your GPU support cl_khr_fp64 extension?

Comment: I added info about the device extensions.

Comment: What is `nc_get_var()` doing?

Comment: That's a netcdf routine that loads an array from a netcdf file. http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/group__variables.html#ga68f419843fc4d4cc7c107d9161a55f99

Comment: I think you are missing `for(auto &ev : last_events) clWaitForEvents(1, &ev);` after all `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` are executed for gpu and cpu devices. You need to make sure kernel finished processing previous data before setting new data to temp_ar, temp_ap and temp_az. Btw. you are calling 3 times `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject()` on `temp_ar`.

Comment: Except there are blocking calls to `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject` that wait on last_events before the next call to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()` which wait on events from the map and unmap commands. The screen dump shows the temp buffers are loading correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. I needed to add explicit calls to [`clFlush`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/) to use events across queues. The documentation for [`clFlush`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/) states:

> To use event objects that refer to commands enqueued in a command-queue as event objects to wait on by commands enqueued in a different command-queue, the application must call a clFlush or any blocking commands that perform an implicit flush of the command-queue where the commands that refer to these event objects are enqueued.

This was not clear from the documentation about `cl_event`.